# Cómo enviar el valor del Radio Button con Ajax a PHP al momento de seleccionar

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Hola amigos mi problema es cuando envió mis variables mediante ajax a mi .php.
Me marca un undefine la variable 'data.estado' una vez que regresa, Ya pude traer el elemento que selecciona y obtener su valor pero hay un error en mi regreso de datos del ajax. No se que es. Una ayuda por favor y gracias por darse una vuelta a mi pregunta jejeje :).

Mi código ajax y controlando en radio seleccionado:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ComprobarSeleccion = false;
    $('input[type=radio]').click(function(){

        ComprobarSeleccion = true;
             var request = $.ajax({
             url: "cuestionario.php",
             type: "POST",
             data:{ valor: this.value, verificar:ComprobarSeleccion},
             dataType:'text',
             jsonp:"jsoncallback",
             crossDomain: true,
             cache: false
        });

        request.done(function(data){
            if(data.estado=="seleccionado"){
                alert("Exito");
                unselect();
                //uncheckRadio(this);
            }else{
                alert(data.estado);
                alert("Error");

            }
        });

        request.fail(function( textStatus ) {

            alert( "Error en la petición: " +  JSON.stringify( textStatus));
        });

    });

});
```

Mi código PHP donde intento atrapar el valor del radio button:

```
   $datos = array();
    $a = false;    
    if(isset($_GET['verificar']) && !empty($_GET['verificar'])){
        if($_GET['verificar']){
           $valor = $_GET['valor'];
           $a = true;
           $datos["estado"] = "seleccionado";
        }else{
           $datos["estado"] = "error123";  
           $a = true;

        }
     }

     if($a == true){
         $resultadoJson = json_encode($datos);
         echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $resultadoJson . ');'; 
     }
```

RESUMEN: Lo que quiero es obtener el valor del radio que el usuario selecciono y guardarlo en una consulta preparada para insertar pero será hasta que termine de selecciona una opción por cada  reactivo y tengo muchos. 
Así que pensé enviar el valor al instante que se selecciona el radio y guardarlo en un método y después aguardarlo adentro de una consulta, intento hacer un solo intento con varios insert acumulados:

```
$sql .= "INSERT INTO respuestas (id_alumno, id_pregunta, respuesta) 
                            VALUES ('$id_alumno',$id_pregunta,'$respuesta')";
```

. La verdad no se si estoy tomando el camino más adecuado y eficaz, por favor acepto sugerencias, indicaciones y correcciones. Gracias.

Mi HTML:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me parece que no necesitas mandar el valor del radio boton antes de todo lo demas.  Porque no lo mandas todo junto?

Comment: Podrías mostrar tu código html ?

Comment: Puede ser, @alanfcm gracias por la recomendación.

Comment: puedes hacer un console.log(data) debajo de  request.done(function(data){       para ver que devuelve

Comment: Amigo tienes razón eso no lo había hecho y se imprimio todo mi código HTML pero porque mis etiquetas es raro no le mande eso por las variables. Que esta pasando??

Comment: Diegos yo probé un código parecido en otra pregunta y sólo me funcionaba si quitaba esto de la parte de Ajax:  `jsonp:"jsoncallback",` y poniendo la parte PHP así: `echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . $resultadoJson . ');'; ` si ponía cualquier otra cosa no me funcionaba. Por cierto, este tipo de peticiones sólo se recomiendan cuando la petición se envía a otro dominio que no es el mismo del cliente.

Comment: Buenas noches @A. Cedano ok lo probare pero necesito de tu ayuda porfa podrías orientarme ya que he visto que puedes mucho bueno por lo menos más que yo jejeje y me esta costando trabajo esto, podrás??

Comment: Lo esencial es que la petición Ajax funcione bien. En cuanto a lo otro que preguntas aquí, conviene que envíes la acción del radio button al servidor al cambiarlo únicamente si necesitas ejecutar una acción **particular, exclusiva** que depende sólo del estado de ese radio button, para cambiar algo y seguir trabajando, pero si no, entonces puedes mandar su estado con los otros datos como ya te han comentado otros compañeros. Conviene que aclares eso en la pregunta.

Comment: Ok bueno lo intentare pero primero debo resolver este problema ya que aún me marca error aplicando lo que me indicaste.

Comment: Has un var_dump($datos) antes del if(a==true).. para ver que hay dentro de esta variable.

Comment: Amigo lo hice me manda undefine y cuando cambio mi dataType a jsonp me manda esto: Error en la petición: {"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"load"}  y me trae esto: array(1) {
  ["estado"]=>
  string(12) "seleccionado"
}

Comment: Quítale el `dataType`.

Answer (score 1):

tienes dos problemas:

1. En el archivo php usar $_GET, pero recuerda que las variables las estas enviando por $_POST, por lo tanto corrige:

   ```
   $datos = array();
   $a = false;
   if(isset($_POST['verificar']) && !empty($_POST['verificar'])){
   if($_POST['verificar']){
       $valor = $_POST['valor'];
       $a = true;
       $datos['estado'] = "seleccionado";
   }else{
       $datos['estado'] = "error123";  
       $a = true;
    }
   }

   if($a == true){
   $resultadoJson = json_encode($datos);
   echo $resultadoJson; 
   }
   ```
2. Recuerda que json_encode devuelve en si un JSON, sino un string con la estructura de un JSON. Una vez obtienes los datos es necesario aplicarles JSON.parse para convertirlo en Objeto:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   var ComprobarSeleccion = false;
   $('input[type=radio]').click(function(){

       ComprobarSeleccion = true;
            var request = $.ajax({
            url: "cuestionario.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:{ valor: this.value, verificar:ComprobarSeleccion},
            dataType:'text',
            jsonp:"jsoncallback",
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false
       });

       request.done(function(data){
                   var datos = JSON.parse(data);//Convertir string a Objeto
           if(datos.estado=="seleccionado"){
               alert("Exito");
               unselect();
               //uncheckRadio(this);
           }else{
               alert(datos.estado);
               alert("Error");

           }
       });

       request.fail(function( textStatus ) {

           alert( "Error en la petición: " +  JSON.stringify( textStatus));
       });

   });

   });
   ```

Aplicando estos cambios se debería resolver tu problema. A mi me funcionó.

En vista de que no te funcionó nada de eso, te propongo esto como alternativa a tu código JavaScript (El código php, sigue tal cual como el que te mandé) y a cada Radio Button le agregas el evento onClick que llame a la funcion comprobar:

Html

```
<input type="radio" value="8" id="radio1" name="radio-stacked" onClick="comprobar()">
```

Javascript

```
<script>

    var ComprobarSeleccion = false;
    var ajaxRecarga;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        ajaxRecarga = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        ajaxRecarga = new ActiveXObject("Microsfot.XMLHTTP");
    }

    function comprobar() {

        ComprobarSeleccion = true;

        var drecarga = "valor=" + this.value + "&verificar=" + ComprobarSeleccion;

        ajaxRecarga.onreadystatechange = function()  {
            if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {

                var data = this.responseText;
                alert(data);
                var datos = JSON.parse(data);

                if(datos.estado=="seleccionado"){
                    alert("Exito");
                //unselect();
                }else{
                    alert(datos.estado);
                    alert("Error");
                }
            }
        }
        ajaxRecarga.open("POST", "cuestionario.php", true);
        ajaxRecarga.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        ajaxRecarga.send(drecarga); 
    }
</script>
```

Espero que esta vez si te funcione.

Comment: Amigo puse todo igualito el código y me sigue marcando error no será porque hasta arriba de mi php tengo: session_start();
            if(isset($_SESSION['sesion_iniciada']) == true ){ Y aqui adentro esta todo lo demas en donde intento capturar el valor del input  }  Y aquí afuera esta mi HTML. Será eso????  El error viene desde aquí: echo $resultadoJson;

Comment: Intenta usarlo sin el session_start(), a ver que te dice, lo otro es que no necesariamente tienes que poner todo dentro del if, con que coloques un redireccionamineto o un exit si no se cumple la condición es suficiente.

Comment: Amigo ya use quitando la sesion y eso me salio: mira arriba.

Comment: @DiegosSánchez acabo de corregir algo en mi respuesta, porque por un error en el formato de la publicación un llave en el código de php se había quedado por fuera, no se, si tu lo notaste.

Comment: Si lo había notado e incluso lo volví a probar pero sigue el mismo error.

Comment: Lo probé con la variable de sesión, asi como lo tienes y me funcionó normal, sin inconvenientes. Asi que asumo que tiene que ver con alguna parte de código que no esta en la descripción del problema. Ahí veo que se imprime el json arriba de la etiqueta html y no se porque

Comment: Amigo cuando uso esto:  echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $resultadoJson . ');';    y cambio a  dataType:'text',    jsonp:"jsoncallback",       y borrro var datos = JSON.parse(data);   me muestra el alert de Error y data.estado me muestra undefined

Comment: Si claro, precisamente yo no tuve en cuenta ese $_GET['jsoncallback'], si revisas mi respuesta veras que no lo uso, por a mi con esa variable también me daba error.

Comment: Pues amigo ya probe de las dos formas y nada e incluso quite todo lo que tenia de PHP en mi HTML y dejo puero html el js que publique  y el php que publique osea lo deje todo igual cómo lo publicaste copie pegue todo y mi Html normal y nada. Error.  Ya no se que hacer u otra forma de hacer lo que quiero lograr para tomar otro camino??

Comment: @DiegosSánchez acabe de editar mi respuesta, allí te propongo otra manera, sin usar jquery, sino directamente ajax

Comment: Amigo solo para avisarte probe todo tu código y no me funciono la verdad no se que estara pasando bueno de todos modos gracias por todo es raro ya me canse mi error me lo marca aquí:  var datos = JSON.parse(data);   A ver que hago jejejejje.

Comment: Jejeje suele pasar, que error te dice?

Answer (score 0):

Viendo tu código veo que tienes el evento `click` del `radiobutton` .. se recomienda usar el `change` , luego tus `radiobutton` deben tener en su `html` definido un nombre.

```
<input type="radio" name="colors" value="red" id="myRadioRed">Red color
<input type="radio" name="colors" value="blue" id="myRadioBlue">Blue color
```

Con respecto al evento, para capturarlo `change` debes indicarle el nombre previamente asignado, con lo cual el evento estaría a la escucha de todos los `radiobutton` asociados a dicho nombre y finalmente allí dentro manipulas sus propiedades :

```
$('input[type=radio][name=colors]').change(function() {
    if(this.value == 'red'){
      console.log('Color Rojo seleccionado');
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación amigo. Aún me marca error mi ajax. :(

Answer (score 0):

Buenas amigos ya descubrí mi error, para los que les llegue a pasar esta es la solución:  Mi código en donde capturo los valores de las variables de la petición ajax de mi .php faltaba este pequeño método. Al fin jejej por si alguien no lo sabia así debería quedar:

```
 if($a == true){
     $resultadoJson = json_encode($datos);
     echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $resultadoJson . ');';
     exit(); 
 }
```

Y es por eso que me imprimía todo el código HTML. Gracias por todo y hasta luego amigos.